# Innosetup error mismatched or misplaced quotes on parameters

Tags: inno-setup

Estoy intentando esto en inno setup:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
Filename: "schtasks"; Parameters: "/Create /F /SC HOURLY /TN ""Vivete"" /TR "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Vivete\dist\Vivete.exe"'{app}Vviete.exe' par1""";  Flags: runhidden
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error :

> mismatched or misplaced quotes on parameters

Comment: Pareciera que el problema lo tienes aquí: `Parameters: "/Create /F /SC HOURLY /TN ""Vivete"" /TR "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Vivete\dist\Vivete.exe"'{app}Vviete.exe' par1"""` estás cerrando con tres comillas dobles pero creo que tienes una de más.

Comment: es decir quito las  que están al final?

Comment: No, lo que digo es que pareciera que tienes dos comillas de más, deja solo una al final.

Comment: no no se soluciona el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Filename: "schtasks"; Parameters: "/Create /F /SC HOURLY /TN Vivete /TR C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Vivete\dist\Vivete.exe'{app}Vivete.exe' par1";  Flags: runhidden
```

Lo logré quitando todas las comillas en parámetros exceptuando las de `'{app}tuapp.exe'`